# Adding `noremap <C-[> <NOP>` to .vimrc

Tags: vim

My .vimrc file looks like this:

```
noremap <C-[> <NOP>
```

I would expect this to map the `Ctrl + [` key to `nothing` but instead when I run `vim` it starts in `REPLACE mode`. This becomes problematic when I add additional lines to my `.vimrc` file because they get entered incorrectly.

What is going on? Does this happen for everyone? If so, how can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21948007/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+Control-Left+Bracket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Control-Left Bracket is char #27, i.e. Escape. <strike>Don't put two fingers into electrical socket</strike> Don't remap it and you won't get weird things going on.

Comment: To add a bit of information… `<Esc>` is not only the key you press to leave insert mode. Vim uses the `<Esc>` *character* a lot under the hood to communicate with the terminal emulator and there even are quite a few keys on your keyboard that send codes containing `<Esc>` to Vim so disabling it or mapping it to something else is bound to create weird problems.